# s3 presigned url POST saying bad bucket name

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm following this [tutorial](https://dev.to/devpato/angular-with-nodejs-image-upload-to-aws-s3-easy-pec) and I switched out the url in src to the presigned URL that is being returned, but I keep getting invalid bucket name and I'm not sure why. I think that's what the tutorial was saying when it says

`Note: Don't forget change the url of the image source to have your bucket name.`

I did a {{this.presignedURl}} and it does output the url to the page so it's definitely being assigned correctly, but I still get the error. What is it I'm doing wrong?

Error:

`Object { headers: {…}, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload: 400 Bad Request", error: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>InvalidBucketName: The specified bucket is not valid.`

angular service

```
  getPreSignedUrl(image: File, userId: string) {
    const queryParams = `?userId=${userId}`;

    return this.http.get(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/upload" + queryParams
    );
  }



  imageUpload(imageForm: FormData) {
    console.log('image uploading');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload',
    imageForm);
   }
```

component.ts

```
onImagePicked(event: Event): void {
    const FILE = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.imageObj = FILE;
  }

  onImageUpload() {
    this.submitListingService
      .getPreSignedUrl(this.urls[0], this.userId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("res below");
        console.log(res);

        this.presignedUrl = res["url"];

        console.log("URL" + this.presignedUrl);
        const imageForm = new FormData();
        imageForm.append("image", this.imageObj);
        this.submitListingService.imageUpload(imageForm).subscribe(res => {
          this.imageUrl = res["image"];
        });
      });
  }
```

html

```
  <input (change)="onImagePicked($event)" placeholder="Upload Image" type="file" />
  <button (click)="onImageUpload()">Upload Image</button>
   {{this.presignedURl}}
  <div *ngIf="imageUrl">
    Preview Image from AWS
    <br />
    <img width="200px" src='{{this.presignedUrl}}' /></div>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the tutorial, it looks like its not giving a pre-signed url. The approach is basically upload an image with `public-read` permissions and read the image using the s3 end point.

according to the tutorial, you should have the bucket url followed by the path.

```
<img width="200px" src="https://my-upload-example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/{{ 
     imageUrl }}" 
/>
```

You should replace the `my-upload-example-bucket` with your s3 bucket name.

#### Cors for S3 Bucket

Also can you allow all the origins until you get this working, then you can restrict the cors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

#### If you want to generate presigned URLs,

You could also easily use a lambda instead of using an express backend to generate pre-signed urls.

```
import AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3_BUCKET = 'bucket-to-presign-example'


const getpresignedUrl = async (fileName, fileType) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();  // Create a new instance of S3

  // Set up the payload of what we are sending to the S3 api
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 5000,
  };

  const presignedURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', s3Params);
  return presignedURL;
}
```

you could also use `putObject` to generate a presigned url for upload purposes.

Comment: I changed the code to the bucket, but now it says 403 forbidden Access Denied. I created the IAM user per the tutorial and I'm using the secretAccessKey and accessKeyId from that IAM user. Is there something I need to do with bucket policy or something as well?

Comment: You only need to use IAM credentials for the backend to do the upload. Is the upload working fine

Comment: You definitely need to setup cros setup on the bucket. Have you done that

Comment: I added cors configuration above. Also I'm not sure how I would point to the presignedUrl if I'm changing the src to just say the bucket. I realize the tutorial doesn't talk about presignedUrls, but it's something I've been trying to understand and piece together with this solution.

Comment: If it's presigned url, it will already have the bucket url along with the signature. If your presigned url is for "GetObject" , you can directly add that to the `src` of img tag. You can also generate presigned url for `PutObject` which can be used to upload directly to S3 with out going through the backend API. The backend API is still needed to generate the presigned URLs